What verb tense and aspect are 'is lost'?
We pair present simple of 'to be' with past simple of 'to lose' in "All hope is lost". Is there syntax taxonomy for this?
I'm tasked with writing out dance steps, eg "left foot is weighted" indicates repetitive nature of the instruction whereas the left foot was weighted describes an event.

Besides a foot and weighting, haven't you got something less obscure? I know a bit about dance and have not heard that...

lost is not past simple there.   You could say "Weight is placed on the left foot."   I don't know what you mean when you say "is weighted"  indicates something repetitive.   The present simple can be used to express an ongoing state, which isn't necessarily any form of repetition or recurrence.


All hope is lost.

The structure is
Subject + Copula + Subject Complement
where the subject complement is the adjective lost.
Collins Dictionary gives an example in its sense 6 for lost:

The sense of community is lost.

lost
The same structure applies to

left foot is weighted

where weighted, meaning burdened or weight-bearing,
is an adjective functioning as subject complement.

Exactly. It just so happens that many adjectives used in the cited context are in fact past participles used adjectivally. But it could just as well be a simple adjective: All hope is futile. I'm not familiar with choreography terminology, so I'm not sure what weighted means here, but perhaps it's equivalent to the continuous participle (also used adjectivally) The left foot is weight-bearing.

Thanks, @FumbleFingers.   Yes, we can say weight-bearing.  I've added that to my answer.
